# view update problem on transition

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit, uiview, transition

when flip from one view to a new one, I get refreshing problem. New view contains a navigationItem with two buttons, one right, one left and when transition starts, I see buttons on opposite sides and not correctly positioned until the transition ends. Then view is showed correctly according to xib file. How to solve it??

Comment: Please note that Cocoa is not the iPhone development framework; it is the *Mac* development framework. You're asking about the iPhone, which means you're asking about Cocoa Touch.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like the normal behavior. The subviews of a view visibly migrate to their new positions as the phone rotates. It almost looks like they're tumbling.

Comment: so should I accept it as normal behavior?? in all cases thanks for your replies!

Comment: Whether you like it or not is a matter of design style. It just doesn't indicate a problem beyond the aesthetic.